# How can I stop NTFS-3g from mounting a particular volume?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, ntfs

I have NTFS-3g installed and working. I don't want it to mount my Boot Camp partition; I do want it to mount any other NTFS drives I have. How do I do this?

(The mounted volume list in NTFS-3g's System Preferences page is always empty, for whatever reason, so I can't disable it that way. As I recall, this option puts a file on the disk in the root directory. But what should the file's name be? I'm having no luck with google here...)

OS X 10.10.3.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the **/etc/fstab** file.

`LABEL=BOOTCAMP none ntfs rw,noauto 0 0`

If the label is something other then "BOOTCAMP" set it to what it is.

To edit the **fstab** file, in a Terminal: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

To save the changes press <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> and to exit press <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>